# array is converted as string in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Below is my query:

```
$key = array(1,2);
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($key), '?'));
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.subid IN (".$in.") AND posts.pricing=?  AND posts.Poscode=? ORDER BY posts.Poscode DESC LIMIT 60");
$result = array_merge($key, array($rate,$postcode));
$statement->execute($result);
```

When I replace `$key = array(1,2);` with `$key = array($key);` the query only fetches data for the first ID whereby I assume it converts the array into string.

`$key` also holds the value 1,2 in an array shown below:

```
$a=$data['sub'];

$key0=array();
foreach($a as $v=>$k) 
  {

    $key0[]=$v;

  }

 $key2=implode(',',$key0);
 $key = array($key2);
```

How do I make the PDO understand `$key` holds an array value and not a string?

Comment: shouldn't `$in` supposed to be inside the `IN` clause instead of that undefined `$key2`

Comment: @Ghost, sorry typo, now corrected but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem always using named placeholders. I personally don't like the `?` stuff. You need a placeholder for every value of your in.

See the sample code:

```
$key = array(1,2);
$pricing = "somePricing";
$postcode = "somePostcode";


$bindings = array();
$bindings[] = array(":pricing", $pricing, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$bindings[] = array(":postcode", $postcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$key_placeholders = array();
foreach($key as $k => $v) {
    $placeholder = ":subid".$k;
    $bindings[] = array($placeholder, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $key_placeholders[] = $placeholder;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts "
        . "WHERE posts.subid IN (". implode(",",$key_placeholders).") "
        . "AND posts.pricing=:pricing  "
        . "AND posts.Poscode=:postcode "
        . "ORDER BY posts.Poscode "
        . "DESC LIMIT 60";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($bindings as $b) {
    $statement->bindValue($b[0],$b[1],$b[2]);
}
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: I think this part is causing the issue:
$a=$data['sub'];

$key0=array();
foreach($a as $v=>$k) 
  {
  
    $key0[]=$v;
     
  }
$key2=implode(',',$key0);
$key = array($key2);

Because I tried your code with $key=array(1,2); it works but when replaced with $key=array($key2); it doesn't

Comment: yes, you are right, if you do it with `?` then you need one `?` for every value: `IN (?,?,?)` and that is the reason why you need to pass the values not as imploded string but each as a item in your values-array: `array(1,2,3)`.

Comment: I just noticed that implode is the one converting them as string..but how do I use my array value in your code above?

Comment: you need to use the unimploded `$key0` instead of the imploded `$key2`

Comment: I did and says Array to string conversion in  ERROR

Comment: it should work, too if you use the result of `array_keys($data['sub'])` so you do not need to do the foreach stuff with your `$data['sub']`.  Which is the line that produces the `array to string conversion error`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77587/discussion-between-sherly-and-steven).